# javascript expression not returnig true, when I think it should...?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a newb question, but shouldn't this return true?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const characteristics = ['straight', 'white', 'male']
const amIpartOfDiversity = qualifyingCharacteristics => {
  let isQuaified = true
  for (let i = 0; i < characteristics.length; i++) {
    let characteristic = characteristics[i]
    let characteristicIsQualified = qualifyingCharacteristics ? qualifyingCharacteristics.includes(characteristic) : false
    if (!characteristicIsQualified) {
      isQuaified = false 
    }
  }
  return isQuaified
}

console.log(amIpartOfDiversity())
```

Comment: You aren't passing anything to the function, so `qualifyingCharacteristics` is always `undefined`, so `characteristicIsQualified` is always `false`

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but if you want to check if one characteristic is in the array, just use:  const characteristics = ['straight', 'white', 'male'];
console.log(characteristics.includes('straight'));, or modify that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on what is being expected/what is being passed in. From looking at your code, are you passing in a single value (ie `'white'`) or are you passing in multiple values (ie: `['white', 'male']`)?

If you're just trying to pass in a single string and evaluate if that matches a characteristic in your `characteristics` array, why not simplify it?

```js
const amIPartOfDiversity = (charecteristic) => {
    return !!['straight', 'white', 'male'].includes(charecteristic);
}

console.log(amIPartOfDiversity('white'));
```